# Is there a chart like this...Q

Tags: charts, visualization, powerbi

Does anyone know if a chart like this and where, or how can I get my desired result?

[image]

The teal is are the fees, the black is cost/expenses and the red is the budget.  Any thoughts on how to accomplish this are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look for "stacked bar chart".

Comment: Right. It's a stack bar chart, but it has 3 columns per location. I need two the requirements stacked and the budget beside the stack.

Comment: Would you consider using an R Visualization?

Comment: Sure. Is it possible to do this in R?